# Yandex Maps: Отключить выбор место из всех городов, кроме ․․․

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Мне нужно загружать карту только выбранном городом, чтобы только могли выбрать мест из этово города.

Город я буду выбрать из списка.

Пример. Я буду выбрать города из Италии (Роме , Милан ...)

Answer (score 1):

Примеры [ограничения области просмотра](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/restrict_map_area) и [поиска по своим объектам](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/custom_search) есть в документации API Яндекс.Карт.

Добавлять нужные объекты на карту тоже можно только для конкретных областей. При помощи того же [ObjectManager'а](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_options), а пример [добавления списка городов](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/list_box_layout) тоже есть в песочнице Яндекс.

Если у вас иная задача, стоит уточнить, чем эти примеры вам не подходят.